# How to compute a kronecker calculation in the matrix in r?

Tags: r, matrix, computation

I have 2 matrix, one is 22x22 that are all the regions's freight values and the other one is 22x4 in which there are: `gdp`, `population`, `km` and `emissions`. My goals is to see how much the total emissions for region influence each region. 
My teacher told me to use the kronecker calculation like this (that is an example):

```
newnames_o = function(x) paste(x, "_o", sep = "")
newnames_d = function(x) paste(x, "_d", sep = "")
for (i in min(determinants$Year):max(determinants$Year)) {
if (i == min(determinants$Year)) {
    orig = kronecker(matrix(1, length(unique(determinants[, 2])), 1),     as.matrix(determinants[determinants$Year == i, -c(1:2)]))
    colnames(orig) = sapply(colnames(determinants)[-c(1:2)], newnames_o)
    dest = kronecker(as.matrix(determinants[determinants$Year == i, -c(1:2)]),   matrix(1, length(unique(determinants[, 2])), 1))
    colnames(dest) = sapply(colnames(determinants)[-c(1:2)], newnames_d)
    fulldata = cbind(orig, dest)
    colnames(fulldata) = c(colnames(orig), colnames(dest))
```

How should I do the first calculation: my first region with the other 21 regions and the other 4 variables and then my emissions?